# TypeError: 'KNeighborsClassifier' object is not callable

Tags: python, knn

```
Input
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 10)
print(knn)
Output
KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=10)

Input
knn.fit(X,y)

Output
KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=10)

Input
prediction = knn([[2,4,3,1]])

Output
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-8cba26986f0c> in <module>
----> 1 prediction = knn([[2,4,3,1]])

TypeError: 'KNeighborsClassifier' object is not callable
```

Comment: What's the question here? Indeed, it's not callable. SciKit-Learn's interfaces use the [`predict` method](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.predict) for predicting